# Disable alt-menu in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, hotkeys, alt

On the keyboard when you press the "Alt" in the active window there appears an alternate menu:

[image: 1]

Can you please tell me how to disable this feature without disable the key, because it is used to switch the language, and a few functions?

Comment: Are you saying the Explorer hotkeys are interfering with other default system keyboard shortcuts? Which ones? Have you tried Win+Space for switching languages?

Comment: "Alt" often prevents accidental pressing - activates alternative menu in a text editor and type the text stops. In addition, if you press the "Alt", then after pressing the "Win" does not appear "Start"

Answer (score 1):

I forgot my user e-mail SomeNameDub, for this reason I write from SomenameDubDub.

The question is solved.

At the moment, could not find a way to disable the alt-menu by means of Windows. For this reason, using the program AutoHotkey.

To turn off the alt-menu should:
1) Download the program AutoHotkey.
2) Go to the Libraries -> Documents.
3) In the Documents folder, select the file Autohotkey.ahk and open it with notepad.
4) When the file you want to insert a line **~LAlt Up:: return**

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a mapping tool, like Auto Hot Key to resolve this issue!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Given that this is a standard feature - probably somewhere you can disable it. I would suggest that it is possible to register.

Answer (score 0):

as found somewhere @MS

1. Press Windows Key+ R, type Regedit and hit Enter.
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Preference
3. Now create or modify a String Value (REG_SZ) called On and set its value to 1
4. Logoff your computer to take effect.

cheers Jens

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you disable that it have been the same even in the old versions of windows but they looked different

Well a key mapping tool might mess up with other stuffs like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: A tip since I see a whole lot of suggested edits from you. Simply adding kbd tags to a post is *not* considered a substantial edit and quite often will be rejected. See meta discussions like [this one](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6824) for more. You don't want too many rejected edits against your name, I assure you.

Comment: @Karan sorry about that i really didn't mean to mess up anything as u know i am a new here

Comment: No harm done. :) Enthusiastic editors who want to improve the site are always appreciated, which is why I didn't want you to get banned due to too many rejected edits. There are certain editing guidelines to be followed, and generally minor changes, especially on such a large scale, aren't encouraged. If you're ever in doubt about the best course of action to follow, head on over to chat or search/post in meta, and someone will be sure to help you out. If it's rep you're after, good answers are *the* best and fastest way to garner it. All the best and welcome to SU!

Comment: @Karan Thanks i really love helping people i will do my best to post good answers